# The proof of decomposition law for cyclotomic field (Neukirch)

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

I don't understand the latter half of the proof of J. Neukirch "Algebraic Number Theory" chapter 1 section 10 proposition 10.3.

The situation is below:

> Let $n$ be a natural number, $p$ be a prime not dividing $n$, and $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal dividing $p$.
>
> And let $\zeta$ be a primitive $n$-th root of unity, $\phi_n(X)$ be a minimal polynomial of $\zeta$.
>
> First, let $\mu_n(R)$ be a set of $n$-th root of unity in a ring $R$, then a natural homomorphism $\mathcal{o}\rightarrow \mathcal{o}/\mathfrak{p}\ (\mathcal{o}\colon =\mathbb{Z}(\zeta)$) induces "bijection"*1 $\mu_n(\mathcal{o})\rightarrow\mu_n(\mathcal{o}/\mathfrak{p})$ and "this sends primitive to primitive" *2.
>
> Next, let $f_p$ be a minimum number with $p^{f_p}\equiv 1\ {\rm mod}\ n$, and we have "$\mathbb{F}_{p^{f_p}}$ is splitting field of $\bar{\phi}_n(X)\colon =\phi_n(X)\ {\rm mod}\ p$".*3
>
> Finally, considering factorization of $\bar{\phi}_n(X)$ on $\mathbb{F}_p$, "all factors are the minimal polynomial of primitive $n$-th root of unity $\bar{\xi}$, and so their degree are $f_p$".*4

What I don't understand are descriptions which are sandwiched by " "(four questions). As for the first "bijection", it is enough the reason of only surjectivity.

And more, I want ask people who have this book where is the definition of $f_p$ used when it is clear we can take $n$ being not divided by $p$(at the middle of this proof).

I'll appreciate even if partial answers.

Comment: It is saying that if $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal contaning $p$ of $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$ and $p \nmid n$ then $a \mapsto a \bmod \mathfrak{p}$ sends the complex (primitive) $n$-th roots of unity to the (primitive) $n$-th roots of unity of the finite field $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_n] /\mathfrak{p}\cong \Bbb{F}_p(\omega_n) \subset \overline{\Bbb{F}_p}$. Proof : factorize $x^n-1$ in both $\Bbb{Q},\Bbb{F}_p$ and deduce the factorization of the cyclotomic polynomial thus the prime ideals of $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$.